# Practical 'lightest' shade of grey for contrast with white

Tags: color-scheme, contrast, displays

I often use a light shade of grey such as rgb(242,242,242) in my designs to provide a subtle contrast to white, e.g. for the background of alternating rows in a table.

I can easily distinguish between this grey and white on my display (a 27" 4K) but on other displays this is not always the case, which reflects badly on my designs and could impact user experience.

Reasons might include badly calibrated / poor quality displays.

Assuming all accessibility standards have been met, is there a 'lightest' shade of grey that:

- Provides a contrast with a white background
- Does not significantly impact the legibility of dark foreground text
- Will be reliably displayed for most users under normal conditions

Comment: This a big challenge because depends on your user screen configuration. I need to make my e-commerce work on IE and I'm successfully using #EBEBEB. I know that is far from a perfect smooth contrast on 4k screens with perfect balance.  But this is real life! :(

Comment: Good feedback - thanks! I've found some good information here as well: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5362/what-screen-contrast-should-a-design-be-optimised-for?rq=1. As you say, it doesn't seem that there is a straightforward answer...

Comment: I solve this by using a border slightly darker than the background but not so dark that it stands out and appears black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rgb(242,242,242)` against `#fff` is about Lc 5, which is marginal even for people with good vision. It is below the invisibility point for many, depending on the spatial characteristics of the element.

For instance, a 1px line is going to be very difficult to see, but a 6px wide line, might be visible to *some*.

Per [APCA guidelines](https://readtech.org/ARC/), the minimum, if you want someone to see it, is **Lc 15**. [Against #fff that is #e1e1e1.](https://www.myndex.com/APCA/?BG=ffffff&TXT=e1e1e1&DEV=G4g&BUF=stux)

You also mentioned that you have a 4K monitor, this makes a difference if you're using 1px lines on a 4K monitor, and somebody's displaying on a standard resolution monitor, such that that 1px line is now ½px, it's  going to get subsumed very much into the background.

### *EDIT to add images to address Devin's comment.*

What is the text in the targets below?
Because #F9 against #FF is close to zero contrast on most sRGB displays.

The #f2 the OP mentions is about Lc 5, #e3 is Lc 14, e1 is Lc 15.2 (not much difference of course), and #c7 is the cutoff for any text at Lc 30.

#### `#f9f9f9` Lc 1

[image: f9 ff]

#### `#f2f2f2` Lc 5

[image: f2 ff]

#### `#e1e1e1` Lc 15

[image: e1 ff]

#### `#c7c7c7` Lc 30

[image: c7 ff]

Again, the spatial is key here. So is the quality of eyesight. Someone with significant contrast sensitivity deficits is going to have a hard time seeing even Lc 15, as will someone with detached vitreous, as an example.

Comment: I believe the information provided may not be entirely accurate. Even though I don't have perfect vision, I can clearly distinguish between the colors #fff and #f9f9f9, even in a relatively small space. I would go as far as to say that #fafafa is also discernible, making it a viable minimum for someone (in this case me). Additionally, the Material Design color used for separator lines was (though I'm not sure if it still is) represented as rgba(0,0,0,0.7), which translates to the HEX value #e3e3e3."

Comment: Hi @Devin , Do you have macular degeneration, retinitis pigmentosa, or open angle glaucoma? Then you have good eyesight. I edited the post to add in sample images. Look at the first one at f9: what does it say? How many bars can you see? If you mean that you can make out the border when you stare at it, sure. But you are also looking for it specifically. The human vision system would ignore it as noise without your consious effort.

Comment: I understand the question is for zebra bars, maybe I misread the question. Either way , you're right I can't read #f9f9f9 there (I can count all bars) but I can see the text on all other versions. If I make an effort I can read f9f9f9 but it's probably because I already could read the other versions. But it's very difficult to read, of course. Then again, I though the question was about the zebra background, and in that case I can see f9f9f9 easily, just as I can see the bars in your first image (just not the text)

Comment: Hi @Devin Ah I see—Well technically, some might say WCAG 2 needs 3:1, but that's also ridiculous. `Lc 1` is at the edge of perception for people with good vision like you. For good vision, `Lc 5` is a minimum for something like a fat divider or zebra. But for impairments, not enough. Someone with low-vision contrast impairment at a PeliRobson 1.0 is going to see the `Lc15` about like that `Lc05`, which is why `Lc15` is the minimum threshold. As an example, I have impaired vision. Even with glasses & a few inches from display, **I can barely read Lc30**.  Enjoy your good vision while you can.

Comment: well, I'm learning a lot from you, thank you very much. I suffer from prebyopia, I use +3 reading glasses for seeing up close and 1.50 glasses for distance vision, but yes, while I don't see anything without glasses, I never noticed any discernible loss in color contrast when using glasses

Comment: Hi @Devin what I'm going to say next may seem unintuitive. Everything about the human division system revolves around its context sensitivity and that includes the context of impairments. Part of the visual cortex ask as a sharpening filter, and if you went without glasses for a period of time, a couple weeks, things would not seem "blurry" per se, but you have a functional deficits in terms of the size of text you can read. Other compensations happen like contrast sensitivity gain adjustment, ... it won't seem "off" per se, until clinically measured.

Comment: Hi @Devin continued: the point I'm getting at, is visual processing through your neurology presents the best interpretation of the world around you to your consciousness, however that is not necessarily an accurate representation of reality. Also, contrast sensitivity (CS) and visual acuity are two separate aspects of visual function. Someone could have good acuity (focus) but poor CS, or vice versa (though poor acuity does reduce CS a bit unless corrected).

Comment: Hi @Devin just a follow up, I reread some of my earlier posts in this thread and some of them might've come across as callous or abrupt, and I apologize if they came across that way, that was not intentional. It is nevertheless an issue with my personal writing style at times.  ...  This conversation had me thinking about a self experiment I conducted about 30 years ago, before I had low vision. I wore glasses for astigmatism. About a month before an eye exam one year, I didn't have any film work lined up, so I decided to take off my glasses, and **not wear them at all, for a full month**. 1/2

Comment: Hi @Devin cont: the interesting thing is, while things certainly looked blurry for the first couple weeks, by the end of the month my vision system had adjusted to showing me things "in focus". When I went to the eye doctor, and did the clinical tests with an eye chart, ***my vision was essentially the same***. So why were things sharper? It turns out the human vision system has a built-in sharpening filter, and attempts to fill in and clean up visual imagery before presenting it to the consciousness. The implication is, it's hard to judge one's own sight.  2/3

Comment: @Devin 3/3  It's hard for a person to know how good or bad they're seeing without clinical tests, in part because our vision system valiantly tries to give us the best possible picture of the world around us... Filtered, cleaned up, and filled in for our enjoyment. It's part of the very complicated nature of vision, and it's why I asked about your eyesight. In closing just to add: vision shifts over our lifetime. Children & teens under age 20 are still developing their contrast sensitivity. Adults over 40 usually develop presbyopia. Our goal is accommodating this wide range of vision. 3/3

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer @Myndex! Nice surprise to get such a good response to this question some years later!

Comment: Hi @MattSaunders some years ago when you posted, we were just starting some of this research, and APCA was not developed in its current form yet. When I recently stumbled upon this, thought it worth answering, considering recent work in this area. ***But also***, your question brings up some important use-case considerations, such as, for alternating table rows with a subtle background change relative to the adjacent row. And there are multiple potential issues, including, as you noted, how displays may clip the highest (or lowest) values. Another is, if there is a border line or not...

Answer (score 2):

Check this, you can find perfect colour https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/