# Is there any science way to find out the suitable contrast for text and background colour?

Tags: color, readability, contrast

Here is the four text with different level of grey:

[image]

As you can see, the first line is very difficult to read, and the last one is the best to read. So, is there any science number behind this contrast and readability? What is the contrast that the human eyes can read easily? Which one is hard? Of course, you can find someone to do testing. But, any proved number had been proof? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What screen contrast should a design be optimised for?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5362/what-screen-contrast-should-a-design-be-optimised-for) and [Choosing colors for a subtle UI](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/choosing-colors-for-a-subtle-ui)

Comment: Here is a usefull tool with lot of information : http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Web Content Accessibility Guidelines ([WCAG2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/))  claimed

> level **AA requires** a contrast ratio of **4.5:1 for normal text** and **3:1
>   for large text**.
>
> Level **AAA requires** a contrast ratio of **7:1 for normal
>   text** and **4.5:1 for large text**.

You can use [contract color checker at WebAIM](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/)

Answer (score 0):

The Guidelines have been specified by the user below.

A tool I like using is the [Colour Contrast Analyser](http://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastAnalyser). A desktop application that allows you to eye drop any color on your screen and outputs the contrast ratio.